# JSQMessagesViewController animated typing indicator

Tags: jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm working on a project that uses the JSQMessagesViewController library. Has anyone successfully animated the typing indicator, and if so could they share their approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi..did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm late for the party but because this also take me a lot of time and my post could help others so I will list my working solution.
I use an APNG (animated PNG, which could have transparent background) as typing indicator so I use APNGKit which provide an UIImageView subclass named APNGImageView

- Copy JSQMessagesTypingIndicatorFooterView.xib from Pods/Pods/JSQMessagesViewController/Resources to your source folder, rename it to MyMessagesTypingIndicatorFooterView.xib (for example)
- Create a class named MyMessagesTypingIndicatorFooterView like so:

  `class MyMessagesTypingIndicatorFooterView: JSQMessagesTypingIndicatorFooterView {
          @IBOutlet weak var animatedImageView: APNGImageView!`

  ```
      override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
          super.draw(rect)

      }

      override func awakeFromNib() {
          super.awakeFromNib();
      }

      public override class func nib() -> UINib! {
          return UINib(nibName: "MyMessagesTypingIndicatorFooterView", bundle: Bundle.main)
      }

      override class func footerReuseIdentifier()->String{
          return "MyMessagesTypingIndicatorFooterView"
      }   
  }
  ```
- Add APNGImageView instance to MyMessagesTypingIndicatorFooterView.xib, reference custom class MyMessagesTypingIndicatorFooterView. Add reference outlet animatedImageView to MyMessagesTypingIndicatorFooterView class.
  [image]
  [image]
- Register custom footer in subclass of JSQMessagesViewController and override viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind

  `class MyMessagesViewController: JSQMessagesViewController{
          override func viewDidLoad() {

          self.collectionView.register(MyMessagesTypingIndicatorFooterView.nib(), 
              forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, 
              withReuseIdentifier: "MyMessagesTypingIndicatorFooterView")}`

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
              if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter{
              let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "MyMessagesTypingIndicatorFooterView", for: indexPath) as! MyMessagesTypingIndicatorFooterView
                  //footerView
                  let image = APNGImage(named: "typing1.png")
                  footerView.animatedImageView.image = image
                  footerView.animatedImageView.startAnimating()
                  return footerView
              }
              return super.collectionView(collectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind: kind, at: indexPath)
          }
      }

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into the `JSQTypingIndicatorFooterView` here is the documentation. http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSQMessagesViewController/7.2.0/Classes/JSQMessagesTypingIndicatorFooterView.html

You can set the `ellipsisColor`

`messageBubbleColor` the color of the bubble it self.

`shouldDisplayOnLeft` to decide if it should be on the left or right.

`collectionView` the collection view it should show on.